# How to run cronjobs and rackup

Tags: ruby, docker, sinatra, alpine-linux

My problem is when run cron and rackup service for ruby sinatra in docker.

file cronjobs 
`* * * * * cd /app && rake parser >> cron.log 2>&1`

file Dockerfile

```
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add --update build-base \ 
mariadb-dev bash dcron

RUN gem install bundler 

WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile .
RUN bundle install && bundle clean
COPY .  /app
COPY cronjobs /etc/crontabs/root

EXPOSE 80

CMD crond -f && rackup --host 0.0.0.0 -p 80
```

When run docker only one service is functional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker container is running while main process inside it is running. So if you want to run two services inside docker container, one of them has to be run in a background mode.

So, `CMD` layer should be the following:

```
CMD ( crond -f & ) && rackup --host 0.0.0.0 -p 80
```